# change qt source code to create a customized qml component

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I need a QML component like a `Dial`, but with full range of rotation.
I read the Dial source code ([source here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/quicktemplates2/qquickdial.cpp) ) and met this:

```
static const qreal startAngleRadians = (M_PI * 2.0) * (4.0 / 6.0);
static const qreal startAngle = -140;
static const qreal endAngleRadians = (M_PI * 2.0) * (5.0 / 6.0);
static const qreal endAngle = 140;

class QQuickDialPrivate : public QQuickControlPrivate
{
    Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC(QQuickDial)

public:
    QQuickDialPrivate()
        : from(0),
          to(1),
          value(0),
          position(0),
          angle(startAngle),
          stepSize(0),
          pressed(false),
          snapMode(QQuickDial::NoSnap),
          wrap(false),
          live(true),
          handle(nullptr)
    {
    }
```

I decided to change this code to resolve my requirement and make a new component. I copied  it to another suorce and header file in my project and change class name but compilation failed!

*Image showing the compilation errors*
[image: compile failed]

How can I compile this code ?

Comment: That is the peril of editing private files. You probably have problems importing parts of the private API. Or you have just copied parts. You can't judge this, with this small snippet of the compiler output. I think your request is quite reasonable, so I'd go for filing a bugreport/feature request, to make the min and max angle configurable. Until then I'd create my own component from scratch, so I have full control over all source files. You might use the *official* code as a *source of inspiration*.

Comment: If you change Qt source code, you should recompile whole Qt. But I'm sure that you need to write your own component, instead of modifying Qt source.

Comment: Btw, you are trying to use PIMPL idiom. What you are doing? Where your other code?

Comment: I just copy the Dial source code to another file , change class name and tried to compile.

Comment: I've been using private modules for a long time. It is only recently that those undefined reference errors started popping, for me and for other users as well. I also filed a bug report on it: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62948

Comment: Before you do something like that, you need to make sure, that you understand the code. Not just a few lines, but almost every line in detail and the rest of the lines in concept. Including all the macros and stuff. To make it work, will take you way longer than just write code that you understand from scratch. If you are not dependent on maximum performance, you would be even faster using only QML.

Comment: There is usually a better way to achieve the goal than mess with private headers. For something as superficial as a GUI control, I'd do one from scratch rather than mess with private apis.

Comment: In this specific case it is the whole of QuickControls 2 you would need to recompile